# How to deal with "incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "str""?

Tags: python, mypy

Let's say I have a code structure like this

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypedDict


class ValDict(TypedDict):
    something: str
    a: A


class A:
    def __init__(self, x: str) -> None:
        if x and isinstance(x, str):
            self.x = x
        else:
            raise ValueError("x has to be a non-empty string")


class B:
    def __init__(self, something: str, a: A) -> None:
        self.something = something
        if isinstance(a, A):
            self.a = a
        else:
            raise ValueError("a has to be of type A")

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, stuff: ValDict) -> B:
        something = stuff.get('something')
        a = stuff.get('a')

        return cls(something, a)
```

and I run `mypy` on this, I will receive 2 errors

> error: Argument 1 to "B" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "str"

> error: Argument 2 to "B" has incompatible type "Optional[A]"; expected "A"

The errors are quite clear: As `.get` can also return `None`, I might not pass the correct types to the `cls` call in my `from_dict` method.

My question is how to avoid it. For the argument `something` I could potentially get away with modifying to

```
something = stuff.get('something', '')
```

but how would I handle the case for `a`? Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `get`? It looks like you don't want what `get` does.

Comment: ...is `get` the only way you know how to retrieve dict entries? Do you not know about `stuff['a']`?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: Good point, that indeed solves it nicely, it seems. Not sure why I used `get`, probably just a habit ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply drop the use of `get` entirely and just access the keys directly. Sure, this raises a `KeyError`, but the class would fail to initialize properly anyway if you pass in anything other than an instance of `A`.

You *could* have a "default instance" of A to use whenever it isn't present in `stuff`, but judging from your `B.__init__` you don't seem to want default parameters.

So the method would become:

```
@classmethod
def from_dict(cls, stuff: ValDict) -> B:
    something = stuff['something']
    a = stuff['a']

    return cls(something, a)
```

This way, three things can happen:

- `stuff` has the proper keys and values -> `B` is initialized
- `stuff` does not have the proper keys -> `KeyError` on `B.from_dict`
- `stuff` has the proper keys, but key `"a"`'s value is not of the proper type -> `ValueError` on `B.__init__`

Comment: Yep, that's also what user235... suggested. Probably indeed the most straightforward way as the `KeyError` is fine in this case.

Comment: For anyone like me, who found this question and is still attempting to use .get, here's a good answer that helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74626323/7298096

Answer (score 0):

mypy is very distrustful, so some assertions of parameters before they are passed in can help:

```
arg_1 = "something"
arg_2 = A()

assert isistance(arg_1, str)
assert isistance(arg_2, A)

# and call your code without linting failing with an incompatible type warning.
b = B(arg_1, arg_2)
```

Edit: I see the assertion are in the class, however mypy would like to be sure of the type BEFORE they are passed to the class.