# Argument 2 to "join" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "str"

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm running mypy pre commit hook to check for any possible type issues and it's keep giving me this error `Argument 2 to "join" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "str"` for the code below:

```py
else:
    renamed_paths_dict: CustomConnectorRenameDict = {
         "old_path": os.path.join(
                self.temp_dir, change["file_path"]
           ),
          "new_path": os.path.join(
                self.temp_dir,
                change["new_file_path"], -> this is the line mypy is talking about
           ),
    }
```

`change["new_file_path"]` can be either a string or `None` but in this specific else block, it'll be never `None`.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: In this case your code is right and `mypy` isn't able to figure out that `change["new_file_path"]` can never be `None`. You can make the message go away using `change["new_file_path"] or ""` but one could object that that is just writing nonsense code to silence a nonsense complaint.

Comment: @BoarGules While the short-circuit falling back to a string like `""` solves the type problem, it is a terrible idea because it opens the door for terrible silent errors, if you mess up and the `new_file_path` value does happen to be `None`.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg You have a point. I did say that I considered it nonsense code, written for a bad reason. I was prepared to accept OP's assurance that  `change["new_file_path"]` can never be `None`. I understand `mypy` and you both think otherwise, despite what OP says, and you both may be right. But I disagree with "terrible silent errors". Passing `""` to `os.path.join()` as a second parameter just appends `os.path.sep`, and since the intent of the code is to create a filename not a folder name, that is bound to result in a runtime error of some sort.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg And ignoring the `mypy` message gives a better outcome. Passing `None` as a second parameter to `os.path.join()` gives a `TypeError` which would be better than any code written to silence the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow me to rewrite your question in such a way that gives a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), throws out all the irrelevant things (unrelated to the actual problem) and keeps only the essentials.

### Question

If the values in a dictionary are of the type `str | None`, but I know for certain that one of them is definitely a `str` (not `None`), how can I tell a static type checker? The following code produces an error with `mypy`:

```py
import os


temp_dir = "tmp"

paths: dict[str, str | None] = {}
...
paths["new_file_path"] = "foo"
...
new_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, paths["new_file_path"])
```

The error:

```
Argument 2 to "join" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
```

### Answer

You *tell* the type checker to expect the value corresponding to the key `"new_file_path"` to be a `str`:

```py
...
paths["new_file_path"] = "foo"
...
assert paths["new_file_path"] is not None
new_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, paths["new_file_path"])
```

Alternatively:

```py
...
assert isinstance(paths["new_file_path"], str)
new_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, paths["new_file_path"])
```

If you don't want to write that extra type guard, you can always use a `type: ignore`, but you should always try and make those as narrow as possible by using the correct error code to silence:

```py
new_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, paths["new_file_path"])  # type: ignore[arg-type]
```

But I would **not** go that route. The assertion has the added benefit of also giving you a clean and immediately obvious error, if you make a mistake somewhere and the `new_file_path` value happens to be `None`.

I would also **absolutely not** go the route of short-circuiting with `paths["new_file_path"] or "some string"`. This is even more dangerous because it may introduce silent bugs into your code since you said that you *expect* the `new_file_path` value to be a string. If you make a mistake, the code would give you a path to `tmp/some string` without raising an error.

---

### PS

Thanks to @SUTerliakov for pointing out that assertions about specific dictionary values are not entirely safe. If you want to be really precise and safe, you should use an intermediary variable for this:

```py
...
new_file_path = paths["new_file_path"]
assert new_file_path is not None  # isinstance(new_file_path, str)
new_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, new_file_path)
```

For the sake of completeness, you could also use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) like this:

```py
from typing import cast
...
new_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, cast(str, paths["new_file_path"]))
```

But this has essentially the same effect as a well placed and specific `type: ignore`, so I would still recommend the `assert`.

Comment: Great writeup, could you mention `cast` here? It's maybe worse than a type assertion for type correctness (for reasons similar to short-circuiting drawbacks), but sometimes is much cleaner (e.g. in a comprehension).

Comment: Ough. I thought `mypy` disallowed this kind of cheating when adding type guards/assertions on concrete keys before usage, but they don't. Beware that this **is unsafe** (see [this playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=47f047f90539d8f342b6ddc39a01922e) by me). You're allowed to modify the dictionary between guarding and using. Should I open an issue or it was the team decision to allow this explicitly?..

Comment: @SUTerliakov I am not part of the team, so I have no idea. Good question. I suppose in that case the only _ironclad_ way would be to put the value in its own variable.

Comment: Upon some investigation, I'm sure that `mypy` team decided to go this way intentionally for usage convenience. Instance attributes have the similar treatment (narrowing is not invalidated after another access). Moreover, I'd say that this kind of narrowing is only safe for dict-like or list-like types that don't have custom `__getitem__` and instances that don't override `__getattr__`/`__getattribute__` & only for attributes that are not descriptors. So, such narrowing should be *almost* always disallowed, and only intermediate variable is bullet-proof. Walrus operator should get more popular!

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options:

- ignore errors from mypy for this line by adding the comment `# type: ignore`:

```py
else:
    renamed_paths_dict: CustomConnectorRenameDict = {
         "old_path": os.path.join(
                self.temp_dir, change["file_path"]
           ),
          "new_path": os.path.join(
                self.temp_dir,
                change["new_file_path"],  # type: ignore
           ),
    }
```

- give a default value to the variable:

```py
else:
    renamed_paths_dict: CustomConnectorRenameDict = {
         "old_path": os.path.join(
                self.temp_dir, change["file_path"]
           ),
          "new_path": os.path.join(
                self.temp_dir,
                change["new_file_path"] or "",
           ),
    }
```

- add an assertion at the beginning of the `else` statement (will bring a warning of bandit if you use it):

```py
else:
    assert change["new_file_path"] is not None
    renamed_paths_dict: CustomConnectorRenameDict = {
         "old_path": os.path.join(
                self.temp_dir, change["file_path"]
           ),
          "new_path": os.path.join(
                self.temp_dir,
                change["new_file_path"],
           ),
    }
```